# Laravel - how to pass a nullable parameter to middleware?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I know you can pass a param to middleware by doing something like this:

```
Route::get('books', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('convert-string-bool:available');
```

But what if that `available` param is nullable in the request, and so might not always be present? Laravel will throw an exception in the Route file in this case.

Should this logic be handled in the middleware, and we just take all params from the request?

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $field)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $data = $this->convertStringBooleans($data, $field);

        $request->replace($data);

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Converts all string booleans to booleans
     *
     * @param   array  $data
     * @return  array
     */
    private function convertStringBooleans($data, $key)
    {
        $value = $data[$key];

        if ($value === 'true' || $value === 'TRUE') {
            $data[$key] = true;
        }

        if ($value === 'false' || $value === 'FALSE') {
            $data[$key] = false;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, could you elaborate further? The `available` parameter is a string, not a variable.

Comment: would you like to show the handle signature of your middleware ... as you can have optional parameters and a variable amount of parameters as well

Comment: Sure, I've updated with my middleware handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this works -

```
class SampleMiddleware
{
     public function handle($request, Closure $next , $field = null)
    {   
        // code

        return $next($request);
   
    }
 }
```

Comment: this is correct, I was mistaken that the exception occurred in the Route, it actually reaches the middleware and so can be dealt with.